# How does setPosition work?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am unsure on how to use [`setPosition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3asetPosition) (Parsec library). Here is an extremely simple piece of code which should read the first 3 characters of the second line of a text.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

content = ["This is the first line",
           "and this is the second one",
           "not to talk about the third one"]

txt = unlines content

main = parseTest myPar txt

myPar = getPosition >>= \oldPos ->
        let newPos = setSourceLine oldPos 2 in
        setPosition newPos >>
        count 3 anyChar
```

Still, the output is "Thi" and not "and" as I would excpect... I feel I am missing somethning very simple, but alas, I don't know what; can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

The `setPosition` function changes what position Parsec reports for errors, but does not affect where in the stream of tokens the parsing *actually is*. It is used as a primitive for back-ends that need to do fancy things: preprocessors that must report positions in other files, parsers that operate on streams of non-`Char` tokens, and so forth.